# CSS 100vh not taking entire viewport

Tags: html, css

I need help with my css. I wanted the background to take up the entire viewport using 100vh but it's not working. The meta tag for the viewport is already included. The box-sizing is already set up as well. When I tried inspecting the page using the chrome dev tool, there seems to be no margin or padding creating the space below. BTW I'm using Bulma CSS.

```
<section class="section is-paddingless>
    <div class="columns is-vcentered has-background-primary" style="height: 100vh">
       <div class="column is-4 is-flex">
          <div class="container">Sample text</div>
       </div> 
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: could you provide the code that you are using?

Comment: @GiddharthSupta the html code goes like this
`<section class="section is-paddingless">
            <div class="columns is-vcentered has-background-primary">
                <div class="column is-4 is-flex">
                    <div class="container">Sample text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>`

Comment: try removing the `<section>...</section>` wrapper. If that fixes the issue then it has something to do with the classes you used for `<section>`

Comment: It would be helpful for others who come across this question if you could edit the question with the code you provided in your comment.

Comment: @GiddharthSupta I tried it just now. It didn't work. The blank space below still exists.

Comment: You should try to check your CSS classes. Without the CSS code it is hard to debug this issue. It would be easier if you add your HTML and CSS code to the question

Comment: @GiddharthSupta Thanks for the advice! I edited my question and added them above.

Comment: you have just provided the HTML code. Please provide the CSS code as well

Comment: @GiddharthSupta there's no CSS code. that's just it. the classes are defined from Bulma CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. section class attribute has a missing quote symbol " .
Change it from: `<section class="section is-paddingless>` To: `<section class="section is-paddingless">`

B. Add `is-marginless` class to the section's child div.

Final html:

```
<section class="section is-paddingless">
    <div class="columns is-vcentered has-background-primary is-marginless" style="height: 100vh">
       <div class="column is-4 is-flex">
          <div class="container">Sample text</div>
       </div> 
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Could you please explain howadding the class "is-marginless" worked? There seems to be no margin when I inspected the div with the class "columns".

Comment: Colums indeed have margins: .columns:last-child {
    margin-bottom: -.75rem;
}
.columns {
    margin-left: -.75rem;
    margin-right: -.75rem;
    margin-top: -.75rem;
} Here, margin-top seems to be dominant and therefore, the div is pulled upwards.